# Oracle CPU usage exceeds 100%

Tags: oracle12c

I need to monitor the CPU consumption on Oracle 12c and for this I am using the following piece of code:

```
SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    username,
                    sid,
                    round( (cpu_usage / (
                        SELECT
                            SUM(value) total_cpu_usage
                        FROM
                            v$sesstat t
                            INNER JOIN v$session s ON(t.sid = s.sid)
                            INNER JOIN v$statname n ON(t.statistic# = n.statistic#)
                        WHERE
                            n.name LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
                            AND   nvl(s.sql_exec_start,s.prev_exec_start) >= SYSDATE - 1 / 24
                            AND   s.status = 'ACTIVE'
                    ) ) * 100,2) cpu_usage_per_cent,
                    module_info,
                    client_info,
                    machine
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            nvl(s.username,'Oracle Internal Proc.') username,
                            s.sid,
                            t.value cpu_usage,
                            nvl(s.module,s.program) module_info,
                            DECODE(s.osuser,'oracle',s.client_info,s.osuser) client_info,
                            s.machine
                        FROM
                            v$sesstat t
                            INNER JOIN v$session s ON ( t.sid = s.sid )
                            INNER JOIN v$statname n ON ( t.statistic# = n.statistic# )
                        WHERE
                            n.name LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
                            AND   nvl(s.sql_exec_start,s.prev_exec_start) >= SYSDATE - 1 / 24
                            AND   s.status = 'ACTIVE'
                    ) s1
            )
        WHERE
            cpu_usage_per_cent > 0;
```

so far so good, but from time to time, the SUM(CPU_USAGE_PER_CENT) exceeds 100%. More over, sometimes, it exceeds 100% for a single connection.

Can someone explains me why so?
I would expect that SUM (CPU_USAGE_PER_CENT) to be (rarely) 100% and never to exceed 100% for a single connection.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my problem occurred because of the ROUND opperation:

```
round( (cpu_usage / (
                        SELECT
                            SUM(value) total_cpu_usage
                        FROM
                            v$sesstat t
                            INNER JOIN v$session s ON(t.sid = s.sid)
                            INNER JOIN v$statname n ON(t.statistic# = n.statistic#)
                        WHERE
                            n.name LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
                            AND   nvl(s.sql_exec_start,s.prev_exec_start) >= SYSDATE - 1 / 24
                            AND   s.status = 'ACTIVE'
                    ) ) * 100,2)
```

The 2 parts of the division operation between "cpu_usage" and "SUM(value)" generates 2 different statistics values.

I replaced the all SELECT statement with:

```
WITH main_select AS (
    SELECT
        nvl(s.username,'Oracle Internal Proc.') username,
        s.sid,
        t.value cpu_usage,
        nvl(s.module,s.program) module_info,
        DECODE(s.osuser,'oracle',s.client_info,s.osuser) client_info,
        s.machine
    FROM
        v$sesstat t
        INNER JOIN v$session s ON ( t.sid = s.sid )
        INNER JOIN v$statname n ON ( t.statistic# = n.statistic# )
    WHERE
        n.name LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
        AND   nvl(s.sql_exec_start,s.prev_exec_start) >= SYSDATE - 1 / 24
        AND   s.status = 'ACTIVE'
),sum_select AS (
    SELECT
        SUM(cpu_usage) suma
    FROM
        main_select
) SELECT
    username,
    sid,
    round( (main_select.cpu_usage / suma) * 100,2) cpu_usage,
    module_info,
    client_info,
    machine
  FROM
    main_select,
    sum_select
  WHERE
    round( (main_select.cpu_usage / suma) * 100,2) > 0;
```

With this, the statistic view will be interrogated only once and will have same values in all operations.